# Magento related products disappears with item max qty in cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In Magento we have set "Display Out of Stock Products" => "Yes"

On product pages, we have a "Related products" section (`related.phml` => `if($this->getItems()->getSize()):`)

However when `Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart` has been reached, the product disappears from the related products (as well as upsells).

Why is this and how can I display these products anyway?

Comment: could you please provide url of site and maximum qty limit ?

Comment: Did you clear the cache and reindex after you set the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is had nothing to do with the `max_qty`, but at any time, when a product is in the cart, it disappears from the related products or upsells.

In the `Related.php` file, `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()` needs to be removed / commented out.